# DataNode is not starting on hadoop multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, bigdata

I removed contents from hadoop tmp directory,  dropped current folder from namenode directory, formatted namenode but got an exception: **org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0**.

My configuration is as follows:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>        
        <name>fs.default.name</name>         
        <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>         
        <description>NameNode URI</description>     
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>         
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>         
        <value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/namenode</value>        
        <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>     
    </property>
    <property>         
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>         
        <value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/datanode</value>        
        <description>DataNode directory</description>
    </property>           
    <property>         
        <name>dfs.replication</name>         
        <value>2</value>     
    </property>     
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
            <value>master:10020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>master:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>master:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>master:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**data node log**

```
2017-01-20 16:27:21,927 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-01-20 16:27:23,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2017-01-20 16:27:23,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2017-01-20 16:27:23,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2017-01-20 16:27:23,448 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2017-01-20 16:27:23,450 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is master
2017-01-20 16:27:23,461 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2017-01-20 16:27:23,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:50010
2017-01-20 16:27:23,493 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2017-01-20 16:27:23,493 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 5
2017-01-20 16:27:23,650 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2017-01-20 16:27:23,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2017-01-20 16:27:23,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.datanode is not defined
2017-01-20 16:27:23,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2017-01-20 16:27:23,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context datanode
2017-01-20 16:27:23,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2017-01-20 16:27:23,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2017-01-20 16:27:23,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException
java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:919)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer.<init>(DatanodeHttpServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startInfoServer(DataNode.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:1112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2509)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:914)
    ... 10 more
2017-01-20 16:27:23,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Shutdown complete.
2017-01-20 16:27:23,728 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:919)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer.<init>(DatanodeHttpServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startInfoServer(DataNode.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:1112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2509)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:914)
    ... 10 more
2017-01-20 16:27:23,730 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-01-20 16:27:23,735 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at master/10.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if anything is running on port 9000?

Comment: The datanode is up now. The problem has automatically gone after restarting systems. Thanks Harinder for your prompt reply.

Comment: Good to know :)